# How can i get two distinct records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I Have address table and I am trying to select the max ID 2 rows base on the AddressType_ID (AddressType_ID is a PHYSICAL or MAILING Type. Physical has Value 1 and Mailing has Value 2) Can you please guide me with a logic.

```
Address_id  Foreign_Key  AddressLine1     Addresstype_id
1849        1854         182 SE 136th Rd         1
3287        1854         PO Box 285              2
32330       1854         182 SE 139th Rd         1
32331       1854         PO Box 288              2
```

I am trying to do select all the columns value of address ID 32330 and 32331 bases on the addresstype_Id. What could be the logic to get those two record?

Comment: And what do you want in the other columns?  I don't see two distinct rows.

Comment: What logic determines that the addresses with Ids 32330 and 32331 should be selected over the ones with Ids 1849 and 3287?

Comment: How do you decide which rows to return? This doesn't make sense just yet....

Comment: I want to see the last 2 rows when I do join the primary key 1854 with address table foreign key 1854

Comment: @Diado I was wondering if we can do count on AddresstType_ID and if the count is greater then 1 then select the MAx Address_ID rows?

Comment: @RohilPatel
If i understand your problem you need two rows- one for each address type id for a given Foreign key which should have latest address id data

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem you need two rows- one for each address type id for a given Foreign key which should have latest address id data

in that case, use the below query using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) windowing function

```
select 
Address_id,
Foreign_Key,
AddressLine1,
Addresstype_id
from
(
select 
*, 
rn= row_number() over( partition by foreign_key,type order by address_id desc)
from youraddresstable
) t
where rn= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UNION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT TOP (1)
Address_id, Foreign_Key, AddressLine1, Addresstype_id
FROM yourAddressTable
WHERE Addresstype_id = 1
ORDER BY Address_id DESC

UNION ALL

SELECT TOP (1)
Address_id, Foreign_Key, AddressLine1, Addresstype_id
FROM yourAddressTable
WHERE Addresstype_id = 2
ORDER BY Address_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number() function with ties... method :

```
select top (1) with ties, *
from table t
order by row_number() over (partition by foreign_key,type order by address_id desc);
```

However, i find you have `PK` i.e `address_id`, then you can also express it as  subquery with correlation approach like that :

```
select t.*
from tabel t
where address_id = (select max(t1.address_id) 
                    from table t1 
                    where t1.foreign_key = t.foreign_key and t1.type = t.type 
                   );
```